# angular 2 - 'No component factory found for component' in ROUTES loaded from json (even with entryComponents config )

Tags: angular, angular2-router

My application requires dynamic loading of routes based on user, so the routing path is received as json from Database and parse to Routes object using JSON Parser. Dynamic route config working well if go with `loadChildren` parameter instead of `component` parameter, so in this case application routing to `/dash`, `/contacts` works successfully, but when route to `\home` application throws

Error : `No component factory found for HomeComponent`

I have tried configure the `HomeComponent` in `entryComponents: [HomeComponent ]` of `NgModule` in `app.modules.ts` file too, but issue not resolved

Route Json:

```
[{"path":"dash","loadChildren":"app/dash/dash.lazy.module#DashBoardModule"},
 {"path":"contacts","loadChildren":"app/contacts/contacts.lazy.module#ContactsModule"},
{"path":"home","component":"HomeComponent"}, 
{"path":"home","component":"HomeComponent",
"children": 
[{ "path": "child",   "loadChildren":"app/child/child.lazy.module#LazyModule", 
"outlet": "mainoutlet" }]
}]
```

Json to Routes

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
......
appRoutes: Routes;
 routejson: string

public loadRouteFromString() {
    this.routejson = httpcalltogetRouteJsonString();
    this.appRoutes = JSON.parse(this.routejson);
    this.router.resetConfig(this.appRoutes);
    this.router.navigate(['/dash']);   
  }
...
}
```